# CollectionView Cell order messes up on scroll

Tags: swift, uicollectionview

I'm trying to alternate the color of my collection view cells like this: [image]

But when I scroll down and then scroll back up, all the cells get reordered like this:

[image]

This is my code:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int { 
    return 100
        
}
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "yearlyBookshelfCell", for: indexPath) as! yearlyBookshelfCell
    cell.bookLabel.text = "\(indexPath.item)"
    if indexPath.item % 2 != 0 {               
        cell.bookView.backgroundColor = .darkGray
    }
    return cell
}    
func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    return 1
}  
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    let width  = (view.frame.width)
    return CGSize(width: view.frame.width/11, height: view.frame.width/3)
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a common problem with new iOS developers and table views/collection views.

The rule: When you return a cell in your cellForItemAt/cellForRowAt method, you always need to fully configure the cell. Don't assume it comes to you as a blank page.

Your if statement says `if indexPath.item % 2 != 0` (if the item count is even) then set the background color to gray.

What if the item value is odd? You leave it whatever color it was to start with. I'm guessing that your cells start out with a blue background color. But, what if this is a recycled cell that was gray last time it was used?

The way your code is written, that cell will fall through the if statement and its (gray) background color won't get changed..

You need an else clause:

```
        if indexPath.item % 2 != 0 {               
            cell.bookView.backgroundColor = .darkGray
        } else {
            cell.bookView.backgroundColor = .blue // Or whatever the default color is
        }
```

And you need to do that for every single property of your cell that might ever change. If every 100th cell gets a box around it, then you need to write code that removes the box if it's not one of those rare 1 out of 100 cells, or you will wind up picking up a recycled cell that has a box around it from the last time it was used.